# Delaying loading a partial + controller on page load/refresh

Tags: authentication, angularjs, routes, loading, delay

I'm trying to delay loading other controllers until authentication has taken place in my MainCtrl.

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
...
    <div ng-view>
        ...
    </div>
...
</body>
```

MainCtrl:

```
var checkAuth = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    userAuth.isAuthenticated(

    function () {
        $rootScope.user = userAuth.user.data;
        deferred.resolve();
    }, function () {
        $rootScope.user = false;
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

$scope.$watch('$location.path()', function () {

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
        checkAuth();

    });
});
```

What I want is for the checkAuth function to run and then if the user is authorised, to load a partial and controller.

I have tried various solutions as suggested in similar questions ([Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker), [Angular.js delaying controller initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356185/angular-js-delaying-controller-initialization), [AngularJS - prevent not authenticated user from accessing given routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905547/angularjs-prevent-not-authenticated-user-from-accessing-given-routes)) but **the problem is that none of them work when the page is refreshed or if the user is arriving from an external page**. I've tried to use $locationChangeSuccess to run the authentication on page load but the partial controller doesn't wait for the authentication to be run before loading.

Can anyone suggest a better solution or where I might be going wrong with my approach?

Comment: What is your current code relating to loading partial? Partials are not loaded until you use manually load it in your code.

Comment: @NiallRyan Use `$routeProvider`'s `resolve`.

Comment: @Codezilla Have tried that and it only works within the app, so if a user types in a URL to navigate directly to a route, or if the user refreshes the page, the function in the resolve property will not run.

Comment: @NiallRyan In the above case do you get any error or the controller does not wait for the auth to be run before loading?

Comment: @Codezilla The controller doesn't wait for the auth to be run.

Comment: @sza I'm using ng-view to load templates/partials, defined using $routeProvider in app.js, the standard approach.

Comment: @NiallRyan Using `resolve` should work. Generally it resolves all the dependencies before instantiating the controller.

Comment: @Codezilla I thought so too but it doesn't work unless you're already in the app and using links to navigate, if you try to use the address bar to navigate, or refresh the page, the function in the resolve property does not run.