# How to prevent user from opening admin.html in browser

Tags: node.js, angular

How to prevent user from opening admin.html  in browser if the user is not logged in or if the user is not an admin in node.js + angular? I'm trying to use redirect and checking session but it give me nothing. I still can open admin.html page from browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9CjS.png)

Comment: Maybe one ot these can help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905547/angularjs-prevent-not-authenticated-user-from-accessing-given-routes

https://coderwall.com/p/f6brkg/angularjs-access-control-and-authentication

Comment: If you're serving `admin.html` from a static folder, it will be always accessible to anyone by the Webserver itself

Comment: I created a project on Node.js+Angular I have routes in this project. How I can create redirect  to '/' if the user prints whatever link in searching panel.

Answer (score 0):

[Route Guards](https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards)
 can be implemented for authentication purposes
Ways to redirect in case a non authenticated user tries to access a special route

for more in depth go to [angular site](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: I created a project on Node.js+Angular I have routes in this project. How I can create redirect  to '/' if the user prints whatever link in searching panel.